Default Qty to Produce Value to 1.00 in Material Wizard 1 (AM300010) Screen and Required Quantity to 1.00 in Material Wizard 2 Screen (AM300020)
Hi I have a requirement where I need to default the qty to produce to 1.00 in material wizard 1 screen which I have implemented as follows:
namespace PX.Objects.AM
{
  public class MatlWizard1_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AM.MatlWizard1>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    protected void AMProdItem_Selected_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated baseHandler)
    {
     
baseHandler?.Invoke(cache, e);
            var row = (AMProdItem)e.Row;
             if (row.Selected == true) // Only if the item is selected
        {
            row.QtytoProd = 1.0000m;
        }
      
    }


This works but when I select a record to be sent to Material Wizard 2 screen this grabs the value based on original logic. How can I make sure the value is set to 1.00 across both screens?
Thank you!

the only possible method I found was to default values in material wizard 1 screen, is the code given above. In order to populate 1.00 as the default value in required qty field in material wizard 2 I have used the code below.
 // Use RowSelected to update QtyReq when the row is selected or edited
        protected void AMWrkMatl_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (AMWrkMatl)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            // Force QtyReq to 1.00 whenever a row is selected or edited
            row.QtyReq = 1.00m;
            sender.SetValue<AMWrkMatl.qtyReq>(row, 1.00m);

            PXTrace.WriteInformation("AMWrkMatl_RowSelected: Setting QtyReq to 1.00");
        }

Hope this helps!

I would not use RowSelected for setting any values. It should be for visual UI changes (Enabled, visible, etc.). In your example I would override MatlWizard1.ProcessMatlWork and change (not in cache) the passed in AMProdItem.BaseQtyToProd value to 1 for all orders being processed. This will simulate what the user can do in the UI (change wizard 1 qty so wizard 2 material is all based on qty 1) . You could also just try to your example in your question and set value in cache.

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and it works!
